# How to find the splitter box for cable TV?

Tags: data-wiring, television

I want to move a TV from one room to another.  One room has an active cable connection and the other has an inactive connection.  I cannot find the signal splitter to change the connection.  Any ideas on where the splitter may be located?  This is a 10 year old, single family home.

Answer (score 2):

Basement, attic, crawlspace, & closet (removable panel?). Attached garage?

Possibly does not exist and is a direct run.

Start by finding where the coaxial cable enters your house and try to trace it from there.

If it enters directly behind the working jack, it's likely a direct run by the cable company who did not tie into your existing (questionable quality) wiring.

See also, [Why are most of my cable/coax wires disconnected?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/82912/why-are-most-of-my-cable-coax-wires-disconnected)