# Cable TV, Antenna, Coaxial - what is this thing?

Tags: cables, coaxial-cable, tv-antenna

I'm looking to add an OTA antenna to my home. Over the years, many different cable and dish installers have left thier mark on the home, prior to my ownership. In fact, a dish and all its cables are still on the house. I'm thinking of replacing the dish with an antenna in the same location and using the existing coax, since I like the way it was run.

My question is, what is this thing. (There's cables and splitters all over the side of the house that I plan to clean up.) No cables are currently connected to it that arent cut somewhere else. Do I need it? Can I use it for anything? It is properly grounded, so that's something.

Final note, I'm in a major metro area, only about 10 miles from broadcasting centers, so I don't have to be precise with my antenna placement.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an antenna / satellite combiner. [Appears to be an aftermarket add-on](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DGZ4CDW).

[image: Splitter]

It takes both LNB feeds from the dish, along with the antenna signal, and combines them onto one wire. In this case, it looks like it fed four boxes. Apparently this unit could combine them without a splitter on TV end.

Either way, I wouldn't use it without a satellite dish. A regular signal splitter would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Proceed as if that didn't exist.

There's no markings on it and it's the largest passive splitter I've ever seen. <strike>IDK, maybe it's awesome.</strike> More likely though it doesn't [have a good HZ range](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/82912/why-are-most-of-my-cable-coax-wires-disconnected/82944#82944). "only hook up what you have to, to avoid signal loss." - that means what you actually want is a M-M connector, not even a splitter at all.

Comment: It’s a satellite dish splitter. Note the LNB in labels on the right side, it will not work with cable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a splitter. You should be okay to get rid of it if it's not being used anymore.

Comment: The labels on the right side also tell us that it’s a splitter for a satellite dish.  Not a common cable splitter, it will not work with cable.